# PostgreSQL GROUP BY column must appear in the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT 
COUNT(follow."FK_accountId"),
score.*
FROM
(
    SELECT items.*, AVG(reviews.score) as "averageScore" FROM "ITEM_VARIATION" as items
    INNER JOIN "ITEM_REVIEW" as reviews ON reviews."FK_itemId"=items.id
    GROUP BY items.id
) as score
INNER JOIN "ITEM_FOLLOWER" as follow ON score.id=follow."FK_itemId"
GROUP BY score.id
```

Inner Block works by itself and I believe I followed the same format.
However it outputs error:

```
ERROR:  column "score.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 18:   score.*
           ^
```

Is listing all the columns in score field only solution?
there are over 10 columns to list so I'd like to avoid that solution if it's not the only one

Comment: If you use `SELECT score.id, COUNT(follow."FK_accountId)` in the outer select, it will work.  Not sure if that actually makes sense though.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use correlated subqueries or a lateral join:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT AVG(r.score)
        FROM "ITEM_REVIEW" r
        WHERE r."FK_itemId" = i.id
       ) as averageScore,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM "ITEM_FOLLOWER" f
        WHERE f."FK_itemId" = i.id
       ) 
FROM "ITEM_VARIATION" i;
```

With the right indexes, this is probably faster as well.

Comment: Thank you! Just a small fix for other people in the future, `s.id = f."FK_itemId" ` needs to be fixed as `i.id=f."FK_itemId"`

Answer (score 1):

columns not included on the aggregation must be specified during `group by`

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(follow."FK_accountId"),
    score.id,
    score.name
FROM
(
    SELECT items.id as id, items.name as name, AVG(reviews.score) as "averageScore" FROM "ITEM_VARIATION" as items
    INNER JOIN "ITEM_REVIEW" as reviews ON reviews."FK_itemId"=items.id
    GROUP BY items.id, items.name
) as score
INNER JOIN "ITEM_FOLLOWER" as follow ON score.id=follow."FK_itemId"
GROUP BY score.id, score.name
```

Comment: Your leading sentence is not entirely correct, at least not for Postgres.  In fact, `SELECT items.*` with `GROUP BY items.id` _is_ valid on Postgres, because the primary key `id` column functionally determines all the other columns in that table.  But, your update to the outer query is correct, and this is needed, because it's a query on a derived table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i tried items.*, it wont work in postgresql, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=0Sa0p6cqT7

Comment: You didn't make `id` a primary key column.  You would at least need to do that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the ANSI/ISO SQL standard also defined.. *"Implementation-defined rules may determine other known functional dependencies in T."* (where T is a table/view/subquery result) for Known functional dependencies ... But i am pretty sure PostgreSQL only supports functional dependency based on the tables PRIMARY and UNIQUE constraints ?   If PostgreSQL would support Implementation-defined rules for functional dependency then PostgreSQL would/could see that `score.id -> item.id`  which is unique making the `score` records also possibly functional dependent with the `follow."FK_itemId"`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well indeed PostgreSQL does not support Implementation-defined rules, consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7EUAQL7vd4XwVKM4GV2dy/0) for functional dependencies ... It would/should be possible to say the outer SQL is functional dependent on the inner SQL resultset in the sqlfiddle right? As `a_alias.a` points to `t.a` which has a `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I guess it depends on whether Postgres is smart enough to figure that out :-)